# How to create dimension line in Pyautocad?

Tags: python, autocad, cad

I created rectangle with commands `acad.model.AddLine` and I'd like Autocad to show dimensions of those lines.

Here is my code:

```py
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint

acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists=True)
acad.prompt("Hello, Autocad from Python\n")

print('Using file ' + acad.doc.Name)

width = int(input('Enter width: '))
height = int(input('Enter height: '))

p1 = APoint(0, 0)
p2 = APoint(width, 0)
p3 = APoint(width, height)
p4 = APoint(0, height)

line1 = acad.model.AddLine(p1, p2)
line2 = acad.model.AddLine(p2, p3)
line3 = acad.model.AddLine(p3, p4)
line4 = acad.model.AddLine(p4, p1)
```

I tried to use `acad.model.AddDimAligned(line4, 10)` but it is not working.

Comment: what does "it is not working" mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Rawel,

try this for add dimensions in your drawing.

```
dim1 = acad.model.AddDimAligned(p1, p2, APoint(width/2, -0.5))
```

And continuing like this for the others dimensions. Check this video on my YT if you have more doubts about it: [My YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nFRhp6hZHM).